# How do I install Newtonsoft.json for Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, nuget

I am trying to make Newtonsoft.json available for use in my local Visual Studio 2010 projects. I installed NuGet.Tools on my system. Now I see an item in the Solution Explorer called Service References that wasn't there before, but I don't understand how to use that to reference the Newtonsoft package I also downloaded, which is currently in my Downloads folder. Do I need to move the package to a different location to reference it?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can right click on the project where you want to install newtonsoft nuget package.

You will find an option "Manage NuGet packages".

Then search online for "newtonsoft".

This would add a packages.config file in your project (depending on which framework you are targeting to ).

this new file contains all the nuget dependencies required for this project.

Refer [this blog](http://davidsonsousa.net/en/post/what-is-nuget-and-how-to-install-its-packages-into-visual-studio-2010) for more details

Answer (score 0):

VS2010 is old and is unable to update to the latest NuGet version. This means that adding recent packages will often fail; however, you can often add an older version of a package that has a compatible NuGet version and it will work. This causes the suggested answer by @ManojChoudhari to fail for me. In the case of Newtonsoft.Json, the following worked using the Package Manager Console:

`Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 9.0.1`